# how to implement login using JWT Authentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self,request):
        email = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        token = request.data.get('token')
    
        user = TokenAuthentication(email=email,password=password,token=token)
        if user is not None:
            return Response(user,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This is the function of login via regular tokens but I want to use JWT tokens but can't figure out how.

Comment: https://github.com/tanveer-ahmad74/Dummy try this repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install the **djangorestframework-simplejwt** package by running `pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt`.
2. In Settings.py file add `rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication`  to **DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES**.

In **views.py**:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        
        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        
        if user is None:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        access_token = str(refresh.access_token)
        
        return Response({'access_token': access_token}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: @Ero, If it works you may mark this answer as accepted.